# compare one file (keeping rows order) with a "static" file

Tags: linux, awk

Using the awk call below I was getting good results before, which I think was first checking if values in the 1st column of "seafloor" were in 1st column of "ctd", and if so, it gave the value of 2nd column of "ctd", and always following the row order of "seafloor":

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next} {i=int($1+.5)} i in A {print A[i]}' ctd seafloor
```

This means, if "seafloor" 1st column would have values higher than "ctd" 1st column, it gave a blank space, but left that row missing there.

I presume that it was because my "static" file called "ctd" (change of seawater temperature with depth, where water depth in 1st column, and temperature in 2nd column) only has info up to 3470 m water depth, and my "variable" file called "seafloor" (or water depth) was up to 3470 m water depth.

The "static" file has 3470 rows, 1st row going from 1 to 3470, and 2nd from 1.78 to 23.69:

```
ctd: N = 3470   <1/3470>        <1.78/23.69>
```

The thing is that now "seafloor" goes up to 3862 m water depth (ie. deeper than ctd, which is 3470 as maximum in 2nd column):

```
seafloor: N = 13544     <1773.39/3862.14>
```

I realized that it wasn't working as expected because after using this awk call with these two files I got 9839 records, instead of 13544 records present in "seafloor", ie., I must get 13544 records but zeros (or eg. NaN) in those rows where the 1st column of "seafloor" goes beyond the range of 1st column of "ctd" (eg. for a value of 3471).

I appreciate any hint to solve this, and please let me know if some more clarification is needed, thanks.

PS: ctd file is here: http://pastelink.me/dl/779584, and seafloor file is here: http://pastelink.me/dl/f275bc

EDIT 1:

Just to thanks to Scrutinizer for the new awk call, it works nicely. After using it, I compared this result with my old files (ie. up to 3470 m in both files) and this new output is the same that the old one (ie. using my original awk call). So the problem was basically the maximum depth in "seafloor", that it goes beyond the 3470 m in "ctd".

Comment: Please post data samples here

Comment: @suspectus thanks for the suggestion, the problem is that the sample wouldn't represent the problem because of the row order, that's what I want to solve, are the links I posted broken? please if so let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2; next} {i=int($1+.5); print A[i]+0}' crd seafloor
```

---

The explanation is that by adding a zero to the array element it is forced into numerical context, so if it already contained a number, then nothing changes and if it is empty then it becomes `0` .
Also because the if statement was removed output is printed for every line.

A side effect is that this uses a little bit more memory than it necessary, but it is a little bit simpler. Should memory usage become an issue, then this would be a bit more efficient:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2; next} {i=int($1+.5); print (i in A)?A[i]:0}' ctd seafloor
```

Comment: sorry, fast fingers, I am testing it, please give me some minutes

Comment: That was!! thanks a lot Scrutinizer!! my question now is if you could explain why changing the last part of the call and adding +0 did the trick, it'd be great.